# LP_Solve Model for This Case

Tags: linear-programming, lpsolve

I need help creating a model that can solve the problem below.

```
i01 <= 30;
i02 <= 25;

a01 = 10;
a02 = 12;
a03 = 23;
```

The result should be:

```
     i01   i02  
a01   10     0
a02   12     0
a03    8    15
```

Is that possible?

Comment: What is the question??

Comment: I'll try to explain: I have 2 providers of chicks. They can provide the amount of 30000 and 25000. I have 3 producers of chicken, they can receive 10000, 12000 and 8000. I want to know how can I solve this.
* I can have more than 100 producers.